# No default customer addresses returned in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm pulling customer addresses out of magento with

```
$customers = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
foreach($customers as $customer){

    $primary[$i] = $customer->getPrimaryAddresses();

}
```

The problem is I never get any addresses from that function. I can get the customers addresses via $customer->getAddresses() or $customer->getAdditionalAddresses(); but no primary addresses. I've also tried the getDefaultShippingAddress / getDefaultBillingAddress functions neither of which return any addresses.

Getting a bit annoyed now I just can't figure out whats going on. In the Magento backend I can see which address is set to default/primary so I know the address has been set.

Answer (score 1):

Just leaving this here for the next guy/girl...

As of 1.8

getPrimaryAddresses calls getPrimaryBillingAddress and getPrimaryShippingAddress which calls get getPrimaryAddress with the attribute code default_shipping or default_billing

So either the address is not set as the default or..

Its also possible that the customer (or admin) placed the order but did not save the address to their account (guest). So the getPrimaryBillingAddress method (called by getPrimaryAddresses) of the customer object will return null as the address is persisted in the order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$customers = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
foreach($customers as $customer){    
    $addressId = $customer->getDefaultBilling();
    if ($addressId){
       $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customerAddressId);
       $htmlAddress = $address->format('html');
    }    
}
```

You can find more information here http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/71270/

Comment: That doesn't work because nothing is returned by getDefaultBilling. It's acting as if there is no default billing or shipping set however the admin interface says different.